# How to append settings to a sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin

I have my `build.sbt` file like this:

#### ./build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...))
```

and a second file (in the same folder) like this:

#### ./release.sbt

```
lazy val releaseStuff: Def.Setting[Task[Unit]] = DockerSbtPlugin.releaseStuff
lazy val root = (project in file(".").settings(releaseStuff)
```

But the command `releaseStuff` is not recognized, I get:

```
sbt:sitemap> releaseStuff
[error] Not a valid key: releaseStuff (similar: releasePuff, releaseCough)
[error] releaseStuff
[error]             ^
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Please note that `releaseStuff` depends on a plugin so it does not compile if put inside the `project` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `release.sbt` is, but you can configure `releaseStuff` inside of the `project` folder. You just have to import the applicable plugin packages explicitly.

For example, when I want to use the `native-packager` for docker, I create a `project/docker.scala` file with

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin.autoImport._

object Docker {
  lazy val settings = Seq(
    ...
  )
}
```

and include it from `build.sbt`

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")
  .settings(
    name := "widget",
    Docker.settings
  )
)
```

Comment: 2018 update:

```lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "widget",
    Docker.settings
  )```